# Java Webapp runs fine in Eclipse but not in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, configuration

I have a small Java/Spring MVC REST /Maven app that runs just fine in Eclipse but also when I run the following command from the prompt:

> mvn clean tomcat6:run

My problem is when I do:

> mvn clean package

and push the generated war file to the "webapps" folder in my standalone Tomcat instance, the service doesn't work anymore.

The standalone Tomcat starts up just fine, no error in the logs. Interestingly enough though the standalone instance listens on port 8989 vs. 8080 when I run the app in Eclipse or through the mvn command.

Once the app is up in the standalone Tomcat if I try to hit my service w/ RESTClient I get a 404 back. My custom 404 actually, not the generic one.

Also the static content, like my index.html comes up just fine.

Here is my web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <display-name>Skunk User Interface</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:///${APPS_CONFIG}/log4j.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>skunk</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/skunk-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>skunk</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/skunk/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Healthcheck mapping -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>skunk</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/health/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/404.htm</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

And the skunk-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Load configuration settings -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
      <property name="searchContextAttributes" value="true" />
      <property name="contextOverride" value="true" />
      <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
      <property name="locations">
        <list>
          <value>classpath:config/application.properties</value>
          <value>file:///${APPS_CONFIG}/application.properties</value>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate" 
    c:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

  <!-- Auto scan the components -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.skunk.myapp" />
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <cache:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/ehcache.xml"/>
    </bean> 

  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

</beans>
```

Is there anything in that configuration that would explain why any request to the dispatcher servlet return 404 instead of routing to the controller?

Thanks

---

**UPDATE:**

Adding log outputs from Tomcat Standalone.

catalina.[date].log:

```
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;.
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:28 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 673 ms
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive skunk.war
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:44 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:44 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:44 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/19  config=null
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 16106 ms
```

localhost.[date].log:

```
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [C:\Users\my.user\Tomcat\webapps\skunk\]
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [file:///${APPS_CONFIG}/log4j.xml]
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'skunk'
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 13, 2012 1:47:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you merely copy `yourproject.war` to Tomcat's `webapps` folder and let the default deployer kick in (which expands `yourproject.war` to a directory named `yourproject`) then you should be aware that the default Tomcat logic is to make your app available under the context path (read: URL) of `/yourproject`.

If you want the app to be available under the root context (`/`) you should configure Tomcat appropriately.

Comment: And that's fine, I'm actually testing using http://localhost:8989/skunk/myService. So I would assume that should work right?

Comment: What is the war filename? What port is Tomcat configured to run on? Have you taken a look at *all* of the tomcat log files - what do they say when deploying your war and starting up?

Comment: the war file is skunk.war and btw I hadn't touched any of the configuration files and after taking a peek it turns out the 8989 port was defined in there. I switched that back to 8080 for starter, it didn't fix anything but it's more consistent.

Comment: I think since Tomcat has the app registered as `/skunk`, and your servlet-mapping is `/skunk/*`, you need to be accessing http://localhost:8080/skunk/skunk/myService. I'd recommend changing the servlet-mapping to DispatcherServlet to `/*` so you can use the original (sane) URL.

Comment: I figured it out before finding your comment but since your comment is the solution and I can't accept my own answer for 48hours you might as well get the credits for it. :)

Answer (score 1):

So this is your combination.

App - Environment Status
Eclipse->Working
Eclipse Embedded TOMCAT -> working
Standalone TOMCAT -> Not working

See the Eclipse Tomcat preferences, it might have added class path and library path which would make the Tomcat to identify. Faced similar problem in the past.

Also, your static content works fine. It implies that some important jar to run is present in eclipse classpath which is not visible in Standalone Tomcat.

Cheers

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if that makes a difference but I don't have an Eclipse embedded TOMCAT, I think maven is using its own Tomcat plugin when I do "mvn clean tomcat6:run". However I think you're onto something w/ the missing jar and classpath potential differences. I'll dig in that direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I had to change the servlet mapping in web.xml from this:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>skunk</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/skunk/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

to this:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>skunk</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

To be able to reach the service using the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/skunk/myService
```

The original mapping I had in there meant I would have had to type in:

```
http://localhost:8080/skunk/skunk/myService
```

to reach my service... *sigh*

Thank you guys!